# $8x-y=9$ intersects hyperbola, $\frac{x^2}{16}-\frac{y^2}{2023}=9$ in $A$ and $B$.The ⊥ of $AB$ intersects the axes at $C$ and $D$.Find area of $COD$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, triangles, graphing-functions

**Problem**

In the Cartesian rectangular system $xOy$, the line $8x - y = 9$ intersects the hyperbola

$\frac{x^2}{16} - \frac{y^2}{2023} = 9$

in $A$ and $B$. The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ intersects the axes $Ox$ and $Oy$ in $C$ and $D$. Find the area of triangle $COD$.

- This problem is from the team round of a local high school math competition that has ended

**My Work**

We need to find the intersection points (A and B), so we have use the two equations to solve for these coordinates.

(1) $y = 8x-9$

Plug this into the second equation.

$\frac{x^2}{16} - \frac{(8x-9)^2}{2023} = 9$

$2023x^2 - 16(64x^2 - 144x + 81) = 16 \cdot 2023 \cdot 9$

$999 x^2 + 2304 x - 292608 = 0$

This equation seems super messy, am I going on the correct path? Am I required to use the quadratic formula? After I solve for x and y, I will find the midpoint and slope to find the equation of the perpendicular bisector and then use that to calculate the area of the triangle, but I am having trouble solving for x and y currently. I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: You can find the midpoint of AB, so that you can know the equation of CD.

Comment: @ItozDarbien Yes, but it will be very difficult to find the midpoint of AB, because it will be very hard to solve this quadratic equation for x if the use of a calculator is not allowed. Do you have any ideas on how to find the two points of intersection? Thank you!

Comment: $$x_A+x_B=-{2304\over 999}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

Let $A=(x_{1},y_{1}),B=(x_{2},y_{2})$, the midpoint of AB be $M=(\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2},\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2})$.

We have $\frac{{x_{1}}^2}{16}-\frac{{y_{1}}^2}{2023}=9,\frac{{x_{2}}^2}{16}-\frac{{y_{2}}^2}{2023}=9$

So $(\frac{{x_{1}}^2-{x_{2}}^2}{16})-(\frac{{y_{1}}^2-{y_{2}}^2}{2023})=0$

So $\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{x_{1}+x_{2}}⋅\frac{y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}}=\frac{2023}{16}$

It is easy to see that $\frac{y_{1}-y_{2}}{x_{1}-x_{2}}$ is the slope of AB, and $\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{x_{1}+x_{2}}=\frac{\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2}-0}{\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2}-0}$, so $\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{x_{1}+x_{2}}$ is the slope of OM.(O=(0,0))

So $OM:y=\frac{2023}{128}x$.

Now can you know how to solve this problem?